# Excel vba syntax error formula value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to populate a table with formula but I could not get the last line to wok. The first row to be completed for column P is 11, then depending on the number of rows (fyrowCount) to be populated, I want it to increase by 1 each time.

If i use the following formula, it works but can't figure out the correct syntax in vba.

Formula `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&[Item ID'#]&"'!$P$" & 11), "")`

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Table35[Item ID'#]")) = 0 Then
        'Range is empty!

            For y = 2 To fyrowCount + 1
                Range("A" & y).Select
                Z = 9 + y
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1) = wsName
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""'""&[Item ID'#]&""'!$G$7""), """")"
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""'""&[Item ID'#]&""'!$G$6""), """")"
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).Value = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""'""&[Item ID'#]&""'!$G$8""), """")"
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Value = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""'""&[Item ID'#]&""'!$G$9""), """")"
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""'""&[Item ID'#]&""'!$P$"" & z), """")"

            Next y
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap `Value` for `Formula` like so: `Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Formula =`

---

On a seperate note, none of your `Range` or `Cells` objects are qualified with a worksheet. This can be problematic. I highly recomend explicity stating where these objects are. (`Sheets("x").Cells(y, 1) = wsName`).

Also, you do not need to `.Select` a cell here as seen below.

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Table35[Item ID'#]")) = 0 Then
            For y = 2 To fyrowCount + 1
              Z = 9 + y
                Cells(y, 1) = wsName
                Cells(y, 2).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""'""&[Item ID'#]&""'!$G$7""), """")"
                Cells(y, 3).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""'""&[Item ID'#]&""'!$G$6""), """")"
                Cells(y, 4).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""'""&[Item ID'#]&""'!$G$8""), """")"
                Cells(y, 5).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""'""&[Item ID'#]&""'!$G$9""), """")"
                Cells(y, 6).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""'""&[Item ID'#]&""'!$P$"" & z "), """")"
            Next y
    End If
```

Comment: it didn't work after replacing .Value with .Formula.  The formula was changed to `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&[Item ID'#]&"'!$P$" &  z), "")`